# Autocomplete angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create an autocomplete using angular material. I created a project but I am missing a references and I couldn't figure out which one.
After that I have to get the data from the GetEmployees method from DataFromTheDataBase.cs

The link to the project is :

https://plnkr.co/edit/jVdkOb8q5V9BK4xkTiga?p=preview

Thank you in advance. My method to get the data from the GetEmployees is :

```
function getEmployees() {
  return $http.get('../Admin/GetEmployees/').then(function(response) {
    return response.data;
  }, function failureCallback(response) {
    reject("Error!");
  });
}
```

Comment: `response` isn't a function

Comment: How do I need to modify the code? Do I need to just return data

Comment: return `response.data` but also need to `return $http` if you plan to call that function and use another then() to pass the data to scope

Comment: Do you have a minute to look at the project that I created in plnkr

Comment: Could you show me how to return $http in my method.

Comment: Try this https://plnkr.co/edit/cpmUphuLjZOyUxEMvRQ1?p=preview. Nothing was changed in html...just added a json file and modified script

Comment: Thank you, It works but when I select the record it shows [object Object],

Comment: ok..I only got the display part working. I never even selected one. You'll have to fine tune the rest of it

Comment: In the real code a method is returning json. How can I call this method if the method name is GetEmployees

Comment: your server would deliver json also ... all you have to modify is the url in `$http.get`

Comment: I modified the method getEmployees() on the top. Is it correct

Comment: Also when I search and enter b is showing wrong suggestions.

Comment: it works...is looking for a `b` anywhere...can see the letter is a different colr in dropdown. I don't know what behavior is wanted so I used angular `$filter` . If you want different you will need to modify the filter functions

Comment: Please realize this isn't a code writing service.... I got the bare functionality working. You will have to do whatever else it requires

Comment: Thank you I realized that. Do you do one to one paid help. How can I vote for your answer/comment.